# Write an efficient code for the below program?

Tags: java

I wanted to check, for 12 digit numbers, if they belonged to the Fibonacci series. I wrote the following code but it seems unefficient and I faced a timeout error. How could I optimize my code ?

```
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Long> test_list=new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> final_list=new ArrayList<>();
    long cases=sc.nextLong();

    for(int i=0;i<cases;i++)
    {
        long input=sc.nextLong();
        test_list.add(input);
    }

    for(int j=0;j<test_list.size();j++)
    {
        long check_number=test_list.get(j);
        long a=0l,b=1l,c=0l;
        while(c<check_number)
        {
            c=a+b;
            a=b;
            b=c;
        }
        if(c == check_number)
        {
            final_list.add("IsFibo");
        }
        else
        {
            final_list.add("IsNotFibo");
        }

    }

    for(String s:final_list)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Comment: @DharmeshPorwal has he googled **what**?  I can't think of a Google search that is going to be helpful.  Can you?  Have you tried it?

Comment: Why are you calculating the fibonacci series each time?. You know the number is of `12` digits, you could *maybe* hardcode the values?. Calculate them only once, keep a *local cache*?

Comment: @ajb A sort would be `n log(n)`, whereas storing relevant values of the series (12 digits) in an hashtable and then looking up in this table would be `O(n)`. Yet, it might not be extendable to higher values of the series (due to memory) and then a sort on the inputted values would be a good idea to keep a `O(n)` memory complexity (supposed to be lower than the size required to store ncessary values of the series) while having a fairly good computation time

Comment: @Dici It looked like TheLostMind was on the right track, that's why I deleted my comments.  Memory shouldn't be a concern.  The series only goes for 92 elements before the values can't fit into a `long`.

Comment: @ajb - There are only 5 12-digit  fib numbers. They can easily fit in an array. So yes, the complexity would be *theoretically* O(n), but *in reality* a max of 5 times.

Comment: @TheLostMind I think he knows it. BTW, the complexity here has to be measured relatively to the number of inputted values, not the number of 12 digits fibonacci numbers, don't you think so ?

Comment: @Dici - We are calculating the fib series, so the result will already be sorted :P

Comment: @TheLostMind it was about sorting the inputted values so that we only have to compute fibonacci values once, but since there are so few of them it is no use and it is better storing them, so I agree with you (from the moment I knew there are only five possibilities)

Answer (score 1):

easy hardcode solution for 12 digit fibonacci numbers.

```
long f55 = 139583862445L;
long f56 = 225851433717L;
long f57 = 365435296162L;
long f58 = 591286729879L;
long f59 = 956722026041L;    

for(int j=0;j<test_list.size();j++)
    {
        long n=test_list.get(j);


        if(n == f55 || n == f56 || n == f57 || n == f58 || n == f59)
        {
            final_list.add("IsFibo");
        }
        else
        {
            final_list.add("IsNotFibo");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Long> fibonaci = new ArrayList<Long>(); // Added to store already calculated fibo number
    fibonaci.add(0L);
    fibonaci.add(1L);

    List<Long> test_list = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> final_list = new ArrayList<>();
    long cases = sc.nextLong();

    for (int i = 0; i < cases; i++) {
        long input = sc.nextLong();
        test_list.add(input);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < test_list.size(); j++) {
        long check_number = test_list.get(j);
        long a = fibonaci.get(fibonaci.size()-2), b = fibonaci.get(fibonaci.size() - 1), c = 0l;
        if (check_number > b) { //To Check whether last number in fibo is less than input

            while (c < check_number) {
                c = a + b;
                fibonaci.add(c);
                a = b;
                b = c;
            }
        }
        if (c == check_number || fibonaci.contains(check_number)) {
            final_list.add("IsFibo");
        } else {
            final_list.add("IsNotFibo");
        }

    }
    for (String s : final_list) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

What I did :

- Took one extra list to store already calculated fibonaci numbers.
- Check the input, whether it's greater than the last fibonacci number calculated.
- If yes, then calculate the next fibonacci number until input become less than fibonacci number.
- If no, then check whether your number exist in fibonacci list or not.